# Install ASReview via Python

Tags: python

I am completely new to Python and have just installed Python (version 3.9.0) because I want to install ASReview.
As I try to install the program using the following commands in CMD.exe (I tried the second one based on the Trouble shooting page of ASReview when the first returned Errors):

```
pip install asreview
python -m pip install asreview
```

The same errors keep occuring:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\marloes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\marloes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\marloes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpiskpvvkf'
     cwd: C:\Users\marloes\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5m2g9jva\numpy
Complete output (200 lines):
Running from numpy source directory.
setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
Cythonizing sources
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\marloes\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\marloes\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

(There is way more)

In response to a suggestion I was provided by the command prompt I have already updated to pip 20.2.4.
How can I solve this error?

Thanks on behalf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.9.0 does not have wheel for numpy. If there is no reason to why you would need 3.9.0 I would remove python completely and install a supported version like 3.7 (or 3.8).

If you want to stick with python 3.9 then I would suggest a workaround which is installing pipwin. pipwin is a complementary tool for pip on Windows. pipwin installs unofficial python package binaries for windows provided by Christoph Gohlke here [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

```
pip install pipwin
```

and then install numpy

```
pipwin install numpy
```